Disable class renaming in bun
i have multiple TS-files that each contain an exported class (not using export default syntax).
I want to use bun build to compile these classes into a single js file.
To achieve this I use an entrypoint file that includes all the classes.
For different reasons i need the class names to remain the same as in the original source files. But for some reasons bun renames a few of them, appending a 2 to the name.
I know this is to prevent name collisions, but there are none.
How do i prevent bun from making these name-changes? I ask for either a changes in my code or a configuration that i can pass to bun (preferrably by cli).

Edit: This is the structure of my entrypoint file, the procedure is repeated for each class and function I want included:
import { API } from './API';

const __KEEP__ = (fn: any) => fn;
__KEEP__(API);


"For different reasons i need the class names to remain the same" - what are those reasons? What does your entrypoint file look like, does it re-export the classes or something?

Mostly it is that I have different parts of my app, compiled seperately, that rely on these "library classes", also I have inline scripts that also require them.
The entrypoint just imports all the classes and "uses" them so the bundler does not ignore/remove them (see https://github.com/oven-sh/bun/discussions/10953).

If you want to have them as global variables, you should write your entrypoint so that it exposes these classes under well-defined names. (Typically this is done with export statements, and compiling the module exports to a global namespace, but I don't know bun). How does your entrypoint file look like? Please [edit] your question to share it (its general structure, not the complete file).
